# Need to Display current date in more than one activity using TextView

Tags: android, date, textview

I am creating a android app, in which i want to display the current date. Date supposed to be in TextView component in more than one activity. I want to display the same date across the activities.

Comment: Do you want to display the *same* date across different activities, or the *current* date in each one? Can you give us a little background or context on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to display the same date across different activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the current date in a TextView in an activity can be as simple as this:

```
TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM, YY");
myTextView.setText(dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

You can find references for SimpleDateFormat here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

If you want to ensure that the **exact same** date is shown in all activities, you would need to capture it in the first activity, save it somewhere (the easiest option might be in SharedPreferences), then read it back and print it in each activity.

Comment: Great news. If this answered your question, consider marking it as accepted so others can see. Thanks :)